# Scratches on the upper chamber of newly mochapot!

Tags: espresso, ground-coffee, moka, coffee-machines

I have just got my mocha pot for the first time by enthusiasm but look what i have found! Deep scratches, not one or two, a lot! It almost looks like someone did this intentionally while producing. Why this would be happened? Is it safe for using and normal?

I have already been a little suspicious by going to use 'aluminum' pot, and then seeing this added spice to it.

Could you please navigate me considering heavy metal-health effect, if i should return this and paid back or not?

Thanks indeed.[image]

Comment: Do you know what metal it is?  Were you trying to imply that it is aluminum?

Comment: The material is fully aluminum, yes.

Answer (score 2):

Return it. Forget about heavy metal poisoning. That's not a big concern. The bigger concern is that you'll never be able to clean inside those scratches. It'll make your brew taste terrible with time and use, and risk of disease (fungus in particular) will rise with time.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Your comment is very helpful and pricisely convincing. i have already formed my return code. Have a good day.